# How to get selected value or index of a dropdownlist upon entering a page?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, repeater

I have a product ordering page with various product option dropdownlists which are inside a repeater. The "Add To Cart" button is "inactive" until all the options have a selection. Technically, the "Add To Cart" button has two images: a grey one which is used when the user has not selected choices for all options available to a product and an orange one which is used when the user has made a selection from each dropdownlist field.These images are set by the ShowAddToBasket and HideAddToBasket functions.

The dropdownlist fields are connected in that a selection from the first field will determine a selection for the second and sometimes third field. If the second field is NOT pre-set by the first field, then the second field will determine the value for the third field. The first dropdownlist field is never disabled, but the other two can be based on what options have been selected.

There are a few products that have all 3 of their dropdownlists pre-set to certain choices upon entering their page. This means they are all disabled and cannot be changed by the user. Regardless of whether the user enters in a quantity or not, the "Add To Cart" button NEVER activates. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to change it so that, in these rare circumstances, the "Add to Cart" button is automatically set to active once a quantity has been entered. The dropdownlists still have options selected in these pages--it's just that they are fixed and cannot be changed by the user.

Is there anyway I can get the selected value or selected index of these dropdownlist fields upon entering a product page? I want to be able to check to see if they are truly "empty" or if they do have selections made so I can set the "Add to Cart" button accordingly.

Any help would be great because I'm really stuck on this one! :(

Here is the code behind (I removed a lot of the unimportant functions):

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        string MyPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
        MyPath = MyPath.ToLower();
        _Basket = AbleContext.Current.User.Basket;
        RedirQryStr = "";
        _ProductId = AlwaysConvert.ToInt(Request.QueryString["ProductId"]);
        if (Request.QueryString["LineID"] != null)
        {
            int LineID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["LineID"].ToString());
            int itemIndex = _Basket.Items.IndexOf(LineID);
            BasketItem item = _Basket.Items[itemIndex];
            OldWeight.Text = item.Weight.ToString();
            OldQty.Text = item.Quantity.ToString();
            OldPrice.Text = item.Price.ToString();
        }
        int UnitMeasure = 0;
        SetBaidCustoms(ref UnitMeasure);
        GetPrefinishNote();
        _ProductId = AlwaysConvert.ToInt(Request.QueryString["ProductId"]);
        _Product = ProductDataSource.Load(_ProductId);
        if (_Product != null)
        {

            //GetPercentage();
            int _PieceCount = 0;
            double _SurchargePercent = 0;
            CheckoutHelper.GetItemSurcargePercent(_Product, ref _PieceCount, ref _SurchargePercent);
            SurchargePieceCount.Text = _PieceCount.ToString();
            SurchargePercent.Text = _SurchargePercent.ToString();
            //add weight
            BaseWeight.Value = _Product.Weight.ToString();
            //DISABLE PURCHASE CONTROLS BY DEFAULT
            AddToBasketButton.Visible = false;
            rowQuantity.Visible = false;

            //HANDLE SKU ROW
            trSku.Visible = (ShowSku && (_Product.Sku != string.Empty));
            if (trSku.Visible)
            {
                Sku.Text = _Product.Sku;
            }

            //HANDLE PART/MODEL NUMBER ROW
            trPartNumber.Visible = (ShowPartNumber && (_Product.ModelNumber != string.Empty));
            if (trPartNumber.Visible)
            {
                PartNumber.Text = _Product.ModelNumber;
            }

            //HANDLE REGPRICE ROW
            if (ShowMSRP)
            {
                decimal msrpWithVAT = TaxHelper.GetShopPrice(_Product.MSRP, _Product.TaxCode != null ? _Product.TaxCode.Id : 0);
                if (msrpWithVAT > 0)
                {
                    trRegPrice.Visible = true;
                    RegPrice.Text = msrpWithVAT.LSCurrencyFormat("ulc");
                }
                else trRegPrice.Visible = false;
            }
            else trRegPrice.Visible = false;

            // HANDLE PRICES VISIBILITY
            if (ShowPrice)
            {
                if (!_Product.UseVariablePrice)
                {
                    trBasePrice.Visible = true;
                    BasePrice.Text = _Product.Price.ToString("F2") + BairdLookUp.UnitOfMeasure(UnitMeasure);

                    trOurPrice.Visible = true;
                    trVariablePrice.Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    trOurPrice.Visible = false;
                    trVariablePrice.Visible = true;
                    VariablePrice.Text = _Product.Price.ToString("F2");
                    string varPriceText = string.Empty;
                    Currency userCurrency = AbleContext.Current.User.UserCurrency;
                    decimal userLocalMinimum = userCurrency.ConvertFromBase(_Product.MinimumPrice.HasValue ? _Product.MinimumPrice.Value : 0);
                    decimal userLocalMaximum = userCurrency.ConvertFromBase(_Product.MaximumPrice.HasValue ? _Product.MaximumPrice.Value : 0);
                    if (userLocalMinimum > 0)
                    {
                        if (userLocalMaximum > 0)
                        {
                            varPriceText = string.Format("(between {0} and {1})", userLocalMinimum.LSCurrencyFormat("ulcf"), userLocalMaximum.LSCurrencyFormat("ulcf"));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            varPriceText = string.Format("(at least {0})", userLocalMinimum.LSCurrencyFormat("ulcf"));
                        }
                    }
                    else if (userLocalMaximum > 0)
                    {
                        varPriceText = string.Format("({0} maximum)", userLocalMaximum.LSCurrencyFormat("ulcf"));
                    }
                    phVariablePrice.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(varPriceText));
                }
            }

            //UPDATE QUANTITY LIMITS
            if ((_Product.MinQuantity > 0) && (_Product.MaxQuantity > 0))
            {
                string format = " (min {0}, max {1})";
                QuantityLimitsPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(string.Format(format, _Product.MinQuantity, _Product.MaxQuantity)));
                QuantityX.MinValue = _Product.MinQuantity;
                QuantityX.MaxValue = _Product.MaxQuantity;
            }
            else if (_Product.MinQuantity > 0)
            {
                string format = " (min {0})";
                QuantityLimitsPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(string.Format(format, _Product.MinQuantity)));
                QuantityX.MinValue = _Product.MinQuantity;
            }
            else if (_Product.MaxQuantity > 0)
            {
                string format = " (max {0})";
                QuantityLimitsPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(string.Format(format, _Product.MaxQuantity)));
                QuantityX.MaxValue = _Product.MaxQuantity;
            }

            if (QuantityX.MinValue > 0) QuantityX.Text = QuantityX.MinValue.ToString();

            AddToWishlistButton.Visible = AbleContext.Current.StoreMode == StoreMode.Standard;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Controls.Clear();
        }

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["Action"] != null)
            {
                if (Request.QueryString["Action"].ToString().ToLower() == "edit")
                {
                    SetEdit();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        if (_Product != null)
        {

            if (ViewState["OptionDropDownIds"] != null)
            {
                _OptionDropDownIds = (Hashtable)ViewState["OptionDropDownIds"];
            }
            else
            {
                _OptionDropDownIds = new Hashtable();
            }

            if (ViewState["OptionPickerIds"] != null)
            {
                _OptionPickerIds = (Hashtable)ViewState["OptionPickerIds"];
            }
            else
            {
                _OptionPickerIds = new Hashtable();
            }

            _SelectedOptionChoices = GetSelectedOptionChoices();

            OptionsList.DataSource = GetProductOptions();
            OptionsList.DataBind();
            //set all to the first value
            foreach (RepeaterItem rptItem in OptionsList.Items)
            {
                DropDownList OptionChoices = (DropDownList)rptItem.FindControl("OptionChoices");
                OptionChoices.SelectedIndex = 1;

            }

            TemplatesList.DataSource = GetProductTemplateFields();
            TemplatesList.DataBind();

            KitsList.DataSource = GetProductKitComponents();
            KitsList.DataBind();
        }
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (_Product.MSRP != 0)
            {
                salePrice.Visible = true;
                RetailPrice.Text = _Product.MSRP.ToString("$0.00");

            }

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable ResultTable = ds.Tables.Add("CatTable");
            ResultTable.Columns.Add("OptionID", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            ResultTable.Columns.Add("OptionName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            ResultTable.Columns.Add("LinkHeader", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            foreach (ProductOption PhOpt in _Product.ProductOptions)
            {
                string MasterList = GetProductMaster(_ProductId, PhOpt.OptionId);
                string PerFootVal = "";
                string LinkHeader = "";
                string DefaultOption = "no";
                string PrefinishMin = "0";
                bool VisPlaceholder = true;
                ProductDisplayHelper.TestForVariantDependency(ref SlaveHide, _ProductId, PhOpt, ref PrefinishMin, ref PerFootVal, ref LinkHeader, ref VisPlaceholder, ref HasDefault, ref DefaultOption);
                if (PrefinishMin == "")
                    PrefinishMin = "0";
                DataRow dr = ResultTable.NewRow();
                dr["OptionID"] = PhOpt.OptionId + ":" + MasterList + ":" + PerFootVal + ":" + DefaultOption + ":" + PrefinishMin;
                Option _Option = OptionDataSource.Load(PhOpt.OptionId);
                dr["OptionName"] = _Option.Name;
                dr["LinkHeader"] = LinkHeader;
                ResultTable.Rows.Add(dr);

            }
            //Bind the data to the Repeater
            ItemOptions.DataSource = ds;
            ItemOptions.DataMember = "CatTable";
            ItemOptions.DataBind();
            //determine if buttons show

            if (ItemOptions.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                ShowAddToBasket(1);
                resetBtn.Visible = true;
            }

            else
            {
                HideAddToBasket(3);
            }
            if (Request.QueryString["Action"] != null)
            {
                ShowAddToBasket(1);
                SetDllAssociation(false);
            }
            ShowHideDrops();
        }
    }

    private void HideAddToBasket(int Location)
    {
        AddToBasketButton.Visible = false;
        AddToWishlistButton.Visible = false;
        resetBtn.Visible = false;

        if (Request.QueryString["Action"] == null)
        {
            SelectAll.Visible = true;
            WishGray.Visible = true;
            if (Request.QueryString["OrderItemID"] == null)
                BasketGray.Visible = true;
            else
                UpdateButton.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateButton.Visible = true;
            NewButtons.Visible = false;
        }
        if ((_Product.MinQuantity == 1) & (_Product.MaxQuantity == 1))
        {
            AddToWishlistButton.Visible = false;
            BasketGray.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    private void ShowAddToBasket(int place)
    {
        resetBtn.Visible = true;
        if (Request.QueryString["Action"] != null)
        {
            UpdateButton.Visible = true;
            NewButtons.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateButton.Visible = false;
            SelectAll.Visible = false;
            WishGray.Visible = false;
            BasketGray.Visible = false;
            if (Request.QueryString["OrderItemID"] == null)
            {
                AddToBasketButton.Visible = true;
                resetBtn.Visible = true;
                AddToWishlistButton.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateButton.Visible = true;
                AddToBasketButton.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        if ((_Product.MinQuantity == 1) & (_Product.MaxQuantity == 1))
        {
            AddToWishlistButton.Visible = false;
            BasketGray.Visible = false;
            resetBtn.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    protected void OptionChoices_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;

        if (ddl != null)
        {

            //bb5.Text = "ddl !=null<br />"; works
            List<OptionChoiceItem> ds = (List<OptionChoiceItem>)ddl.DataSource;
            if (ds != null && ds.Count > 0)
            {
                int optionId = ds[0].OptionId;
                Option opt = OptionDataSource.Load(optionId);
                ShowAddToBasket(4);
                OptionChoiceItem oci = ds.FirstOrDefault<OptionChoiceItem>(c => c.Selected);
                if (oci != null)
                {
                    ListItem item = ddl.Items.FindByValue(oci.ChoiceId.ToString());
                    if (item != null)
                    {

                        ddl.ClearSelection();
                        item.Selected = true;
                    }
                }


                if (opt != null && !opt.ShowThumbnails)
                {

                    if (!_OptionDropDownIds.Contains(optionId))
                    {
                        // bb5.Text = "!_OptionDropDownIds.Contains(optionId)<br />"; works
                        _OptionDropDownIds.Add(optionId, ddl.UniqueID);
                    }
                    if (_SelectedOptionChoices.ContainsKey(optionId))
                    {

                        ListItem selectedItem = ddl.Items.FindByValue(_SelectedOptionChoices[optionId].ToString());
                        if (selectedItem != null)
                        {
                            ddl.ClearSelection();
                            selectedItem.Selected = true;
                            //bb5.Text = "true: " + selectedItem.Selected.ToString()+"<br />"; doesn't work
                        }

                    }

                    StringBuilder imageScript = new StringBuilder();
                    imageScript.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n");
                    imageScript.Append("    var " + ddl.ClientID + "_Images = {};\n");

                    foreach (OptionChoice choice in opt.Choices)
                    {

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(choice.ImageUrl))
                        {

                            imageScript.Append("    " + ddl.ClientID + "_Images[" + choice.Id.ToString() + "] = '" + this.Page.ResolveUrl(choice.ImageUrl) + "';\n");
                        }
                    }
                    imageScript.Append("</script>\n");

                    ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
                    if (scriptManager != null)
                    {
                        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), ddl.ClientID, imageScript.ToString(), false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), ddl.ClientID, imageScript.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

            ddl.Attributes.Add("onChange", "OptionSelectionChanged('" + ddl.ClientID + "');");
        }

    }

    protected Dictionary<int, int> GetSelectedOptionChoices()
    {
        HttpRequest request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        Dictionary<int, int> selectedChoices = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            foreach (int key in _OptionDropDownIds.Keys)
            {

                string value = (string)_OptionDropDownIds[key];
                Trace.Write(string.Format("Checking For - OptionId:{0}  DropDownId:{1}", key, value));
                string selectedChoice = request.Form[value];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedChoice))
                {
                    int choiceId = AlwaysConvert.ToInt(selectedChoice);
                    if (choiceId != 0)
                    {

                        Trace.Write(string.Format("Found Selected Choice : {0}  -  {1}", key, choiceId));
                        selectedChoices.Add(key, choiceId);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (int key in _OptionPickerIds.Keys)
            {
                string value = (string)_OptionPickerIds[key];
                Trace.Write(string.Format("Checking For - OptionId:{0}  PickerId:{1}", key, value));
                string selectedChoice = request.Form[value];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedChoice))
                {
                    int choiceId = AlwaysConvert.ToInt(selectedChoice);
                    if (choiceId != 0)
                    {
                        Trace.Write(string.Format("Found Selected Choice : {0}  -  {1}", key, choiceId));
                        selectedChoices.Add(key, choiceId);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string optionList = Request.QueryString["Options"];

            ShowAddToBasket(2);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(optionList))
            {
                string[] optionChoices = optionList.Split(',');
                if (optionChoices != null)
                {

                    foreach (string optionChoice in optionChoices)
                    {
                        OptionChoice choice = OptionChoiceDataSource.Load(AlwaysConvert.ToInt(optionChoice));
                        if (choice != null)
                        {
                            _SelectedOptionChoices.Add(choice.OptionId, choice.Id);
                        }
                    }

                    return _SelectedOptionChoices;
                }

            }

        }

        return selectedChoices;
    }

    protected void SetDDLs(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool isRandom = false;
        if (LengthDDL.Text != "")
            isRandom = true;
        SetDllAssociation(isRandom);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the values in the `Page_Load` event. I don't believe the values are bound yet in `Page_Init`

Comment: I can get only the value of the the last of the three dropdownlists for some reason. And I keep getting a value even on pages where nothing has been selected yet. It's really strange.